# Oauth2 Playground exchange authorization code for token: 400 error

Tags: oauth2-playground

I've been following a basic OAuth 2.0 [tutorial](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/) to create an OAuth 2.0 server. That whole part worked fine, but when I tried to play around with it in the Google OAuth2 playground following [this](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/google-playground/) page I'm getting some errors.

I've followed all the steps as they are in the above link except I used `http://localhost/wordpress/authorize.php?state=xyz` as my authorization endpoint because otherwise I would get an error saying that state was required and I didn't want to edit any code yet.

Now, everything seems to work fine with authorizing the APIs. I'm directed to my localhost site and when I authorize the request I am returned to the OAuth2 Playground. When I go on to the next step and attempt to exchange the returned authorization code for a token, I am given a 400 error.

The whole request/response is as follows:

```
POST /wordpress/token.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-length: 191
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground

code=6d408c28d468db6586320bff3aacf16492489b67&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=newclient&scope=& client_secret=newpass&grant_type=authorization_code
______________________________________________________________________

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 106
Content-type: text/plain

An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://localhost/wordpress/token.php
```

This may be a simple error I've made on my end but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't think the code is really a problem because when I do the tests on the tutorial page everything works fine. I also have not edited any of the files from the library the example uses.  If needed, I can edit this post to include the code to comply with the rule that links may become inactive.

One thing I noticed about the request was this little bit `&scope=&client_secret=newpass&grant_type=authorization_code`. It looks like there is no scope parameter set and I was thinking that might be messing up the results.

If anyone has any experience with OAuth or the OAuth2 Playground and could help me figure out where things went wrong I would be really grateful. Also, I apologize for the long question but I wanted to include as much info as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are hosting your OAuth server on a non accessible network (e.g. localhost). Basically when the  oauth playground tries to exchange the Code for the token it does so using its own server (not using a XHR on the webpage) and this server does not have access to your machine using the URL `http://localhost...`.

To test this with the playground you need to make your OAuth 2.0 server reachable with a public URL or IP address.What you can do instead is expose your local service to the outside/internet. For this you can use services such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/) and you'll get a public URL to your local service which you'll be able to setup the Playground with.

Comment: Added some tips/links to ngrok and localtunnel which are cool services that allow exposing a local URL externally.