# Creating Google Group contact

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to create a group contact using Google Contacts v3.

Following the example, and testing within the OAuth 2.0 Playground, here is my sample code:

```
POST /m8/feeds/groups/default/full/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Gdata-version: 3.0
Content-length: 355
Content-type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer #{auth_code_goes_in_here}#
<atom:entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#group"/>
  <atom:title type="text">Salsa group</atom:title>
  <gd:extendedProperty name="more info about the group">
    <info>Nice people.</info>
  </gd:extendedProperty>
</atom:entry>
```

However, I keep getting the 400 error in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Content-length: 236
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Fri, 11 Mar 2016 05:18:06 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: GSE
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Fri, 11 Mar 2016 05:18:06 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="31,30,29,28,27,26,25"
Content-type: application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml; charset=UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>invalid</code>
  <internalReason>Entry does not have any fields set</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Further to this, I would like to create contacts in Google, with specific Group attached to it. Is this do-able from the 'creating contacts' method? I can't seem to find an example where I can specify the group directly to it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Regards,
Leroy

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325790/oauth2-playground-exchange-authorization-code-for-token-400-error

Comment: When I tested adding contact using the OAuth 2.0 Playground, it worked. It is only not working for creating contact group. Thus, I believe my issue may be different to that.

Answer (score 2):

After some painful research, I found the solution by changing the data from:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
to
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
```